# Draw canvas wrong when upgrade new cordova version for android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, canvas

I have a problem after i upgrade new version of cordova platform. I have an android project that is created by phonegap 2.9.0, I upgraded to cordova 4.1.1 and when app running in mobile. i got a problem .
[image]

The circle after upgrade is not draw good.
This is a code segment to draw the circle.

```
context.beginPath();
            //context.translate(context.canvas.width / 2, context.canvas.height / 2);
            context.arc(0, 0, circleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            context.strokeStyle = '#FCBD33';
            context.stroke();
            var posText=20;
            if(self.ToleranceCircle>99)
                {
                posText=30;
                }
            context.strokeStyle = "black";          
            context.fillText(self.ToleranceCircle, 5,  -circleRadius+15);
            context.fillText(-self.ToleranceCircle, 5,  circleRadius+15);
            context.fillText(self.ToleranceCircle, circleRadius- posText, 15);
            context.fillText(-self.ToleranceCircle, - circleRadius + 5, 15);
```

Anyone have experience about graphic in android can help me.
Thank you.